# Read multiple variables from file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I need to read a file that has lines like

```
user=username1
pass=password1
```

How can I read multiple lines like this into separate variables like username and password?

Would I use awk or grep? I have found ways to read lines into variables with grep but would I need to read the file for each individual item?

The end result is to use these variables to access a database via the command line. So I need to be able to read, store and use these values in other commands.

Comment: You have your values inline or no? You have misformatted your question

Comment: I think it really depends on what do you wish to do with these lines. You could, for example, use `awk` to substitute each line into shell code that would set environmental variables `user$i` and `password$i`, where $i would stand for the line number and then execute the result... Ending up with potentially loads of env. variables (which is probably a bad idea). Or you can process each line in pipe, doing the rest of the work you need to do per each line (much better). It really depends on what you want to do next.

Comment: @vencik I am trying to access a database with these values via the command line so I need to substitute them into another command

Comment: Are there more lines in this input file other than `name=value` lines? What if `name` contain symbols that are not allowed in Unix variable names such as hyphen or colon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) then

Input

```
$ cat file 
user=username1
pass=password1
```

Reading

```
$ user=$(awk -F= '$1=="user"{print $2;exit}' file)
$ pass=$(awk -F= '$1=="pass"{print $2;exit}' file)
```

Output

```
$ echo $user
username1
$ echo $pass
password1
```

Answer (score 2):

if the process which generates the file is safe and has shell syntax just source the file.

```
. ./file
```

Otherwise the file can be processes before to add quotes

```
perl -ne 'if (/^([A-Za-z_]\w*)=(.*)/) {$k=$1;$v=$2;$v=~s/\x27/\x27\\\x27\x27/g;print "$k=\x27$v\x27\n";}' <file >file2
. ./file2
```

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean by safe and no the file doesn't have shell syntax.

Comment: I meant if you are owner of the process, otherwise it must be preprocessed

Comment: Might work on some Linux systems, but the example file name conflicts with the binary `file` so something like `. ./file` is more specific.

Comment: @Peri461 you're right because PATH may not contain `.`

Answer (score 0):

**file.txt**:

```
user=username1
pass=password1
user=username2
pass=password2
user=username3
pass=password3
```

Do to avoid browsing several times the file `file.txt`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

func () {
    echo "user:$1 pass:$2"
}

i=0
while IFS='' read -r line; do
    if [ $i -eq 0 ]; then
        i=1
        user=$(echo ${line} | cut -f2 -d'=')
    else
        i=0
        pass=$(echo ${line} | cut -f2 -d'=')
        func "$user" "$pass"
    fi
done < file.txt
```

Output:

```
user:username1 pass:password1
user:username2 pass:password2
user:username3 pass:password3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop for your file perhaps, but this is probably the functionality you're looking for.

```
$ echo 'user=username1' | awk -F= '{print $2}'
username1
```

Using the `-F` flag sets the delimiter to `=` and we select the 2nd item from the row.